# Bluetooth low energy startLeScan deprecated

Tags: java

I am currently working on an app for android that uses Bluetooth low energy to connect to an IOS device so they can transfer data to each other. The android device is going to be my central and the IOS device is peripheral. However, as this app was created some time ago, the startLeScan method to search for devices has been deprecated and after doing some research I understand that startScan() is the new method I should use. However, I have struggled with implementing this new method in my program.Can someone edit my code to include the new method?

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothGatt gatt;
    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic inputCharacteristic;
    private TextView outputView;
    private EditText inputView;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback;



***    public void receiveMode(View v) {
        bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
    } ***

    public void sendMessage(View v) {
        inputCharacteristic.setValue(inputView.getText().toString());
        gatt.writeCharacteristic(inputCharacteristic);
    }


    private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

            if (getString(R.string.outputUUID).equals(characteristic.getUuid().toString())) {
                final String value = characteristic.getStringValue(0);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        outputView.setText(value);
                    }
                });

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status, final int newState) {
            MainActivity.this.gatt = gatt;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                gatt.discoverServices();
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
            for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
                List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
                for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristics) {
                    if (getString(R.string.outputUUID).equals(characteristic.getUuid().toString())) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
                        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptors().get(0);
                        if (descriptor != null) {
                            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                            gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                        }
                    } else if (getString(R.string.inputUUID).equals(characteristic.getUuid().toString())) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        inputCharacteristic = characteristic;
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        outputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputText);
        inputView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);

        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        if (bluetoothAdapter != null && !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new
                    Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="uk.ac.york.androidtoios2.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="Send Message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:onClick="receiveMode"
        android:text="Connect"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outputText"
        android:text="Message"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
        bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
```

With

```
bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(new ScanCallback() {
 @Override
 public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
 super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
 Log.i(TAG, "Remote device name: " + result.getDevice().getName());
   }
});
```

Comment: I have tried using this new method but I cannot find any devices when the IOS devices is put in peripheral. Not sure why this is

Comment: The android monitor says that 120 frames are being skipped and that the application may be doing too much work on the main thread. The problem is, I am not sure which part of my code I would run on a separate thread.

Comment: Is the IOS device actively advertising its presence? Override the other methods in the ScanCallback to see if there was an error starting the scan.